# How to split string of numbers in to int array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

How to split string containing numbers into int array i.e

```
String s="12345";
int i[]=new int[5]; 
i[0]=1; 
i[1]=2;
i[2]=3; 
i[3]=4; 
i[4]=5;
```

i have tried it by

```
String s="12345";
int i[]=new int[5];
int tem = Integer.parseInt(s);
for(int t=0;t<5;t++){
i[4-t]=tem%10;
tem=tem/10;
}
```

it is giving right answer in above case but in case of
**String s="73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"** 
it fails so any other way or how to use ***split method*** in above case

Comment: You can go through the characters (`charAt`, `length` of `String`) and `-'0'` from them. That would give you the numbers which you can store in an `int[]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29)

```
String str = "12345";
int[] nums = new int[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    nums[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: your solution give correct answer but  cant we use split method here??

Comment: Split method splits your string by an expression. You string contains only numbers so you do not have a regular expression for splitting it. For example if your string would be like "1 2 3 4" you can use method split(" ") and convert each new formed string into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your number wont fit in the integer range nor in long range. Also to note, Your code wont be that efficient due to division and modulas operator as well. Instead you could always use [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) api of String and convert individual characters to a number as give below:

```
String s = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934";
int[] numbers = new int[s.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   numbers[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
Output:
[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 9, 4, 9, 3, 4]
```

Comment: char represents an ASCII/unicode digit (like '1'), and you subtract the smallest possible ASCII/unicode digit from it (e.g. '0'), then you'll be left with the digit's corresponding value i.e. int 1.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line of code:

```
int tem = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

When you enter a large number is string which is outside the range of what an `int` can accomodate, the overflow happens, and thus all of a sudden you are working on a different number than what was in your string.

I would suggest you iterate over each character of the string, and then convert each character to integer:

```
for (char ch: s.toCharArray()) {
    // convert ch to integer, and add to the array.
    intArray[i] = (int)(ch - '0');
    // of course keep incrementing `i`
}
```

Comment: your solution give correct answer but cant we use split method here?? of yes then what is its syntex

Comment: @piyank: You can, but there is no need of. `split()` method would generally be applicable, where you want to split your string based on complex splitter, which involves regex. Here since you just want to read each character, directly getting character array seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use Character wrapper class and get the numeric value and add it to array of in.

```
        String sample = "12345";

        int[] result = new int[sample.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        {
            result[i] = Character.getNumericValue(sample.charAt(i));
        }
```